# Cross-compilation in Racket/Scheme language

Tags: compilation, scheme, racket

Is it possible to compile for Windows or Mac OSX while working in Linux for Racket programming language ([cross-compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler))? DrRacket IDE does not provide any such menu item. Raco help command also did not show any such option:

```
$ raco help make
raco make [ <option> ... ] <file> [<another-file>] ...
 where <option> is one of
  -j <n> : Compile with up to <n> tasks in parallel
  --disable-inline : Disable procedure inlining during compilation
  --disable-constant : Disable enforcement of module constants
  --no-deps : Compile immediate files without updating dependencies
  -p <file>, --prefix <file> : Add elaboration-time prefix file for --no-deps
  --no-prim : Do not assume `scheme' bindings at top level for --no-deps
  -v : Verbose mode
  --vv : Very verbose mode
  --help, -h : Show this help
  -- : Do not treat any remaining argument as a switch (at this level)
 Multiple single-letter switches can be combined after one `-'; for
  example: `-h-' is the same as `-h --'
```

I suspect it is not possible in Racket. Is it possible for any other Scheme or Lisp language? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: As of this writing (though it might change with the port to Chez Scheme), Racket bytecode is platform-independent, so “cross-compiling” is not terribly meaningful. The same bytecode should work on any platform.

Comment: I meant compilation to native machine code.

Comment: Racket JIT compiles the bytecode to native machine code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though both `raco` and DrRacket GUI gives the impression that you can make a native executable it is just the racket executable working as a VM bundled with compiled bytecode. Thus you never actually have native code running that you have written in racket.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it's currently possible, but not yet very simple or reliable. According to [this mailing list message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/bYR1ZF86NGI/5pcS5FYVCgAJ) from Matthew Flatt, dated 2016-01-07:

> We've made some progress, although it's not yet as easy as we'd like.
>
> See
>
> http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/cross-system.html
>
> Suppose you're running on platform X. If you have a Racket installation
>   on X and also a Racket installation for platform Y, then you can use X
>   as described in the docs to run `raco exe` or `raco dist` for Y.
>   Probably.
>
> There are two potential obstacles:
>
> - You need an installation for platform Y.
>
>   If Y is Windows, that's kind of a pain, because racket-lang.org
>     currently only provides an ".exe" installer for Windows. You'd have
>     to install on some Windows machine and then copy over the
>     installation's directory.
>
>   We should probably provide builds for each platform in ".tgz" or
>     ".zip" format, but we haven't set that up, yet.
> - It might not work after all.
>
>   We're using cross-compilation for Windows to build the main Racket
>     distribution, so things are likely to work if Y is Windows. I
>     haven't even tried Y as something like OS X or Linux, though.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible.
this question is I want to ask before.
Now When I need to compile something in another OS, 
I use VirtualBox to launch a vm system to compile it.